# Query MongoDB with object as parameter, not just a particular field equality or whatever

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Is it possible to query MongoDB, but using a C# object (which may be partially populated) as the query parameter?

I.e. find all `foo` in collection where they are **partially or more** equal to my parameter `foo` object.

This is from MondoDB's C# driver page:

```
MongoCollection<BsonDocument> books;
var query = Query.Wrap(new { author = "Kurt Vonnegut" });
foreach (BsonDocument book in books.Find(query)) {
    // do something with book
}
```

I can't see this `.Wrap` method, it doesn't appear to be available anymore.

Does anyone know how I can query my collection using an anonymous object like this or a strongly typed one instead?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use a Bson Serilaization object in order to make your query work.  Check out this page - http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Serialization+Tutorial